# Как в Android 5 добавить иконку приложения в заголовок?

Tags: android

В Android 5.0 используется другой стиль оформления заголовка программы, чем раньше, и значка (иконки приложения) там теперь нет. 
Как его можно туда поместить (вернуть на место) в стандартном проекте ?

Comment: Вопрос никак не относится к android studio и решается одинаково в любой IDE

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял и вы про иконку в `ActionBar` то попробуйте этот код в активити `getSupportActionBar().setIcon();`